# Strava API Python - AttributeError object has no attribute

Tags: python, strava

For those of you who have experience with Strava API - I used the documentation on their developer site: https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Activities-getLoggedInAthleteActivities

However, copying their code over I get an attribute error-

```
AttributeError: 'ActivitiesApi' object has no attribute 'getActivityById'
AttributeError: 'ActivitiesApi' object has no attribute 'getLoggedInAthleteActivities'
```

Any idea why? Obviously inputted my ID/secret/token as from their website. Code below:

```
import time
import swagger_client
from swagger_client.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint

STRAVA_CLIENT_ID = MY_CLIENT_ID
STRAVA_CLIENT_SECRET = 'MY_CLIENT_SECRET'
STRAVA_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN'

swagger_client.configuration.access_token = STRAVA_ACCESS_TOKEN
api_instance = swagger_client.ActivitiesApi()

def get_activity_data():
    activity_id = 3307145226
    includeAllEfforts = True # Boolean | To include all segments efforts. (optional)
    try:
        # Get Activity
        api_response = api_instance.getActivityById(id,
                            includeAllEfforts=includeAllEfforts)
        pprint(api_response)
    except ApiException as e:
        print("Exception when calling ActivitiesApi->getActivityById: %s\n" % e)
    return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have an error for passing the id to `getActivityById`. Your activity id variable is `activity_id` but you're passing in `id`. Not sure if that will fix your issue or not but it's a start.